# Calculating the distance between points and the closest raster cell of a certain value in R

Tags: r, spatial

I am currently trying to calculate the distance a set of points and their closes raster cell of a certain value. So far I have tried to convert the raster file into Points, but I keep getting an error message:
Cannot allot Vector of this size. Is there any other way how I can go around this. My datasets are very large (20.000 Points and a raster layer of an entire country).

so far I have tried:

`library(raster)`

`water_points <- rasterToPoints(land_cover , fun = function(x) {x == 405}) #405 are cells that contain water`

then I would continue like this:

`df$water_dist <-  gDistance(df, water_points)`

I have also tried to use `rastertoPolygons` but it seems to show the same problem

Thank you very much

Comment: Would a [distance transform](https://rdrr.io/cran/imager/man/distance_transform.html) be an option for your case?

Comment: please provide some example data generated by code, or using example files that ship with R